# Who wrote the piyutim of Rosh Hashana/Yom Kippur?

Tags: history, tefilla, yom-kippur, rosh-hashanah-new-year, yotzrot

I don't know if they are technically called "piyutim", but there is a nusach we say on Rosh Hashana/Yom Kippur between "Ata Kadosh" to "Hamelech Hakadosh". Was that decreed by the Anshei Knesses Hagedola, or was it a more modern text? If it is more modern, how is it not a problem of a hefsek?

Comment: I've heard that they date back to, or were inspired by, the Mishna's requirement from Rabbi Yochanan ben Nuri to include the bracha of Malchuyot in Kdushat Hashem.  I don't have a source for this, though.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Rambam (Seder Tefillos Mikol Hashanah)](http://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%A8%D7%9E%D7%91%22%D7%9D_%D7%A1%D7%93%D7%A8_%D7%94%D7%AA%D7%A4%D7%99%D7%9C%D7%94_%28%D7%93%29) calls it מנהג פשוט, a widespread custom, to say these paragraphs (his version is different than ours, but it's recognizable). So it doesn't sound like it goes back to the Anshei Knesses Hagedolah; perhaps it's from the Geonim. (It appears in Siddur R. Amram Gaon, but there are lots of later interpolations there, so I don't know that this proves anything.)

It wouldn't be a problem of hefsek, because you are allowed to insert extra prayers for communal needs even in the first three berachos ([Shulchan Aruch, Orach Chaim 112](http://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%A9%D7%95%D7%9C%D7%97%D7%9F_%D7%A2%D7%A8%D7%95%D7%9A_%D7%90%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%97_%D7%97%D7%99%D7%99%D7%9D_%D7%A7%D7%99%D7%91):1). Certainly, these paragraphs are no worse than the other insertions in the first and last couple of berachos (זכרנו, מי כמוך, etc.), which are allowed.